# Paypal - Redirecting after 10486 in Express Checkout

Tags: paypal

I'm integrating a .Net application with PayPal Express Checkout.

I'm using the PayPal SDK for .Net to call `SetExpressCheckout` and `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`.

I'm using the In-Context javascript API as described in the [Advanced In-Context JavaScript settings](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/javascript_advanced_settings/)

PaymentAction is `Sale`, SolutionType is `Sole`

We've had occasions where we received a `10486` error. [PayPal's recommendation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/) for recovering from this is to redirect back to PayPal with the existing payment token

> Upon receiving this error code, redirect the buyer back to PayPal
>   using the existing Express Checkout token. On the PayPal page, the
>   buyer is presented with an error message explaining the reason for the
>   decline.

I have 2 questions about PayPal's recommendation:

**Doing the redirect**

How should I redirect the buyer back to PayPal? Initially I just use the following JS:

```javascript
paypal.checkout.startFlow(data.token);
```

Should I do the use same JS again after I receive the `10486` error, or use some other method?

**Where is the error message?**

I've already tried using the approach above, as well as manually just redirecting to

`https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=[TOKEN]`

After the redirect I don't see the error message explaining the reason for the decline that the PayPal instructions say I should.

Am I doing something wrong?